# Redirect user to a specific page after login

Tags: c#, asp.net

In web application, after login "ReturnUrl" going to last visited page. How to set to go default.aspx.

I declared code in web.config like this.

```
      <forms name="FormsAuth" loginUrl="Default.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" 
path="/" timeout="200" slidingExpiration="true">
```

But If I close application at `/Private/Admin/ReviewIssue.aspx` page.

When I start again application in login page url has like this

```
    http://localhost:3042/Test/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=
%2fPrivate%2fAdmin%2fReviewIssue.aspx
```

I want from login page to Default.aspx only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is for an ASP.NET web forms project created from the Visual Studio template, go to Register.aspx.cs in the Account folder and edit the code there to be

```
    protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

        Response.Redirect( "~/default.aspx" );
    }
```