# How do I redirect to a page after successful login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I'm fairly new to web forms development, playing around with a project created using the ASP.NET Web Application template in VS 2010. After the user successfully logs in, I want the user redirected to a page I created. How do I modify my project to redirect the user after login? Any samples / tutorials / etc are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect user to a specific page after login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789718/redirect-user-to-a-specific-page-after-login)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To simply redirect to a new page when your user has logged in, use the [DestinationPageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.destinationpageurl.aspx) property of your login control... assuming you're using the `Login` control that is.

If you need to do anything more advanced you can use the [OnLoggedIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin.aspx) event handler for your `Login` control to perform a redirect manually, or add any code for event logging and such.

If you've rolled your own login control, and are just using things like text boxes and button controls, then in your `Button_Click` event, you can just use `Response.Redirect("DestinationHere");` to take your users to a new page.

Comment: how can we pass variable from this?

Answer (score 6):

After you checked for login:

```
Response.Redirect("url");
```

Comment: If, as the OP says, you are using the ASP.NET Web Application template, you are using the Login control, which will ignore a Response.Redirect() in favor of the DestinationPageUrl

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using ASP.NET Login control. There's a DestinationPageUrl property of that control that handles exactly that. If login was successfull user is redirected to URL provided in that property.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="~/Admin/Default.aspx">
</asp:Login>
```

Go to Properties and Set DestinationPageUrl.

Answer (score 0):

```
Server.Transfer( *url*) ?
```

(method on HttpServerUtility)

I know next to nothing about ASP.NET, but from my Java web developer daze, redirect is bad because it involves another network round trip to the browser and back when you really just want to continue processing in another page.

And Response.Redirect() really does issue a 302 response code ("try this other url instead") back to the browser.  yuck. XP

Server.Transfer() looks like the java version of Response.Forward()

Comment: This is old, but I feel like this answer deserves some clarification on why it's not good to use on a login. Server.Transfer behaves very differently than a Response.Redirect in execution. Response.Redirect does issue an additional request, but that's because it calls the browser to redirect. Server.Transfer, however, works like a URL mask since the redirect is done by the server. In this case, the browser would still show the Login url, but the content from the *url* specified. Additional info: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/724972/Difference-Between-Response-Redirect-and-Server-Tr

Comment: I think in that particular case I would configure the app/server to require authentication before accessing certain urls, so (1) the un-authenticated user would issue the GET request for the resource directly, (2) the server would reroute the user to an authentication page but remember the original requested url, (3) upon authentication the server would show the user the original page with the original url in the browser bar. I'm not sure how that works behind the scenes, though; we've hit the limit of my knowledge. :)

Answer (score 0):

**For Sharepoint farm solution development**

```
Page.Response.Redirect("url");
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with Response.Redirect() is the 302. In some browsers (eg Chrome) this causes the new session cookie to be immediately invalidated.

In other words, using that method to redirect causes the user to no longer be logged in, so you did not accomplish your purpose!.