# Configuring reverse proxy in iis to access internal network website in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, reverse-proxy

I have configured reverse proxy to access the internal website through my public website in asp.net from the link below

[Source code](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis)

Now problem is my internal network website is opening,when i click on some link and move to login page,after that when i enter credentials and click ok it again return to login page,but when i open internal website independently login successfully done,can any one suggest me why is it not logging in the page??

Comment: Hard to say without more information on your exact setup - please edit the question to include more detail. Initially though, it sounds like you might be redirecting back to the login page every time instead of to a home page. Check your URL for a query parameter like "?returnUrl=login", and your login page on the server to see if it redirects to another page or just reloads.

Comment: Basically i have deployed a website on server with IP 10.10.1.90,on server i implemented a reverse proxy my website redirecting to another website with IP 10.10.10.11 and this website is only accessible on server 10.10.1.90,now website is opening different URL also working but login page is not working it redirect me to again login page i couldn't understand why is it happening but when i open website 10.10.10.11 on server 10.10.1.90 and provide credentials it redirect me to home page

Comment: What exact URL are you putting in the address bar to log in? Does your proxy (10.10.1.90) include a redirect in the reponse to the login from the browser after a successful login request? Are you proxying all traffic to 10.10.10.11 in IIS, or just the login page?

Comment: http://mywebsite/login.jsp,  mywebsite is 10.10.1.90 while login.jsp page coming from 10.10.10.11 and yes all request redirecting to 10.10.10.11

Comment: Still sounds like the login page is not redirecting away from itself - I think you're logging in and then the browser just reloads the login page since it wasn't instructed otherwise. I suspect that if you log in and then manually visit another page on 10.10.1.90 it would load there as well. Go search for answers on [redirecting after login](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net%5D+redirect+after+login), like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5697586/957950).